# Scroll through the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been thinking about this for weeks, in my spare time, but couldn't find a suitable solution. I want to do something like this Apple page: http://www.apple.com/iphone-5s/. The thing is to scroll to next element when mouse scroll is detected, block the scroll while it animates the scrollTop, and then, if you scrolled the opposite direction, scroll back again. I've rewritten my code in hundreds of ways but none of them work as expected.

This is one of the codes I tried, but it doesn't work either. It has to also determine the next and previous positions, which are represented by the undefined variable `destiny`.

```
var locked = false;
$('body').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
    //prevent page fom scrolling
    if (locked) { return false; };

    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
        //scroll down
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: destiny }, function () {
            locked = false;
        });
    }else {
        //scroll up
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: destiny }, function () {
            locked = false;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What exactly in your provided code doesn't work? Does it lock the mouse from scrolling but doesn't animate the automatic scroll?

Comment: Without seeing your actual code, my suggestion is to use classes instead of your locked variable. Say ".scrollable" and bind your scroll event only when it has .scrollable status which will be removed by jquery when page is scrolling. No need for your extra "destiny" variable if you write them in a series of sections, like Apple did. Hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: @Padarom I don't know, it simply doesn't work properly, it sometimes block, bug or lag, I don't know why.

Comment: @Godinall thanks, could you please explain more deeply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using fullPage plugin:

http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage